# Can I receive a Twilio http POST webhook as Salesforce Integration User?

Tags: apex, integration, httppost, twilio

I have experience receiving data in Salesforce from Twilio via an incoming http POST/GET. If the receiving Apex class fires a Platform Event, which in turn triggers a Flow, the user context for that Flow is Guest Site User -- which is limiting.

Can I receive that Twilio webhook data as the Integration User?

I can't find the docs for this.

Comment: did you look at metadata type `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`?

Comment: Never heard of it! This is very promising... need to learn now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm) for your Apex Trigger firing the Platform Events.

Make sure to use the User field to set the necessary user context. Also while deploying it make sure to reference the PlatformEventConfig with the right Apex Trigger.

Comment: The dev doc you link to is just a reference... doesn't really explain it to someone just learning about it. I found this post by Kapil Devani: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/configuring-platform-event-subscriber-config-using-metadata-devani that gives the broad overview.

Comment: So, that changes the context of the Apex Trigger on the Platform Event... but what about the context for a Flow triggered by that Platform Event? I'll need to test...

Comment: Looks like the configuration file requires the name of the Apex Trigger, nothing about a Flow that is subscribed to the event. So, I'm thinking I'll need to create the flow as an autolaunched flow that is called by the Trigger.

Comment: Ya that should work! Try it out and if it does not work then Trigger is your best option.

Comment: I noticed that the param for inputting the Apex Trigger Name is  <platformEventConsumer>. Wondering what might happen if I put in the name of a Flow. Given all the focus around Flows, it would be great to get this capability. (It would never garner enough votes on the Idea Exchange, but maybe *someone* could suggest that internally? :)

Comment: Note: I tried implementing this with Apex class receiving the twilio inbound data, firing a platform event, having the Platform Event Trigger call a Flow (process automation context), and then adding the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig -- the last part didn't seem to work yesterday. I just tried it this morning and the context has switched to the specified user (Integration User). So... it works, but there was some latency.

Comment: I have heard the latency if folks used tooling API than the metadata API? What tool you user to deploy it?

Comment: I created the file in VS Code and just pushed it to org with a Deploy to Org command. Not sure which api that is.

Comment: That's metadata API and should work fine